# How is $\Vert x \Vert_3$ constrained by $\Vert x \Vert_2$ and $\Vert x \Vert_4$ for $x\in \ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

It seems we can find some $x\in \ell^2$ with $\Vert x \Vert_2=1$ that has $\Vert x \Vert_4=a$ for any $0<a\le 1$.

But can we find an $x$ with $\Vert x \Vert_2=1,\Vert x \Vert_3=b,\Vert x \Vert_4=a$ for every choice of $0<a<b<1$?

(This was inspired by [this longstanding MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18264/2-3-and-4-a-possible-fixed-point-result) that made me curious about the flexibility of the three norms.)

Comment: Since $1/3 = 1/3*1/2 + 2/3*1/4$, I would expect something like $\|x\|_3 \leq \|x\|_2^{1/3} \|x\|_4^{2/3}$, or in other words $b \leq  a^{2/3}$, to be necessary (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space). Alas, I don't have the material to check the details right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is extended version of D. Thomine's comment. It is [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) that for a given real numbers $\{\theta_k:k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\}$$\subset(0,1)$,  such that $\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_k=1$ and real numbers $\{p_k:k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\}\subset\mathbb{R}_+$ we have the following generalized Hölder inequality:
$$
\Vert x\Vert_{p}\leq\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\Vert x\Vert_{p_k}^{\theta_k}
$$
where $p^{-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_k p_k^{-1}$.
In your particular case we take $n=2$, $\theta_1=1/3$, $\theta_2=2/3$, $p_1=2$ and $p_2=4$. Then we get $p=1/3$ and
$$
\Vert x\Vert_3\leq\Vert x\Vert_2^{1/3}\Vert x\Vert_4^{2/3}
$$
which is equivalent to $b\leq a^{2/3}$. Thus in general we can't find $x\in\ell_2$ satisfying all conditions mentioned above.